# I am trying to use structure in c++ but its not working

Tags: c++, opengl, struct, operators

in this method

```
void Sierpinski(GLintPoint points) {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLintPoint T[3] = {{10,10},{600,10},{300,600}};
    int index=rand()%3;
    GLintPoint point=points[index];
    drawDot(point.x, point.y);
    for (int i = 0;i<55000;i++) {
        index=rand()%3;
        point.x=(point.x+points[index].x)/2;
        point.y=(point.y+points[index].y)/2;
        drawDot(point.x,point.y);
    }
    glFlush();
}
```

that uses the structure i made

```
struct GLintPoint {
GLint x,y;
};
```

it says that there is an error and that "no operator "[]" matches these operands, operator types are GLintPoint[int]" where i try to assign a value from points to point.  Well i did use the right brackets and it is an int in there so what is the problem?  FYI this code is to draw the Sierpinski gasket with the user making the initial 3 points by clicking the screen with the mouse.  Just in case you would like to see it here is the whole program.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/Gl.h>
#include "glut.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int screenWidth = 640;
const int screenHeight = 480;

struct GLintPoint {
    GLint x,y;
};

void display (void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glFlush();

}

void drawDot( GLint x, GLint y)
{
glBegin( GL_POINTS );
glVertex2i( x, y );
glEnd();
}

void Sierpinski(GLintPoint points) {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLintPoint T[3] = {{10,10},{600,10},{300,600}};
    int index=rand()%3;
    GLintPoint point=points[index];
    drawDot(point.x, point.y);
    for (int i = 0;i<55000;i++) {
        index=rand()%3;
        point.x=(point.x+points[index].x)/2;
        point.y=(point.y+points[index].y)/2;
        drawDot(point.x,point.y);
    }
    glFlush();
}

void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
    static GLintPoint corner[2];
    static int numCorners = 0;
    if(state == GLUT_DOWN){
        if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON){
            corner[numCorners].x = x;
            corner[numCorners].y = screenHeight - y;
            if(++numCorners ==2 ){
                glRecti(corner[0].x, corner[0].y, corner[1].x,    corner[1].y);
               numCorners = 0;
            glFlush();
        }
    }
        else if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON){
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glFlush();
        }   
}
}

void myInit() {

    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
   glPointSize(2.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluOrtho2D(0.0, (GLdouble)screenWidth, 0.0, (GLdouble)screenHeight);
}



void main (int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,150);
    glutCreateWindow("mouse dots");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutMouseFunc(myMouse);
   myInit();
   glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce that to a [MCVE] please? The compiler error is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: I see nothing about `GLintPoint points` that tells me that it should be index-able.

Answer (score 4):

I'm inferring from the name of the function argument, `points`, that you intend the function to accept an array of points.  But it's actually just written to take one.

So when you write `points[index]` the compiler is looking for `operator[]` in your `GLintPoint` struct (and there isn't one).

If you change the function prototype to take an array of `GLintPoint`s I think you'll have better luck.

Comment: You are right I am not passing an array as the parameter it was a structure of type GLintPoint.  I changed that line from void Sierpinski(GLintPoint points)  to void Sierpinski(GLintPoint points[])  and the code now works thank you.  Well there were some other things I had to change that were wrong but you solved the build errors for me thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you.  You should make sure to mark the answer as accepted since it fixed the problem.  Also since I want the extra rep :)